# SQL Server row level security and Microsoft authentication

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-web-api2, row-level-security

I know that SQL Server's RLS uses Windows Authentication, but is it possible to use external authentication? Like Google or Microsoft auth?

I am doing testing on it using C# Web API 2 can't figure out how.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The [Row-Level-Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security) feature does not use Windows Authentication. You are creating your own function, that is used as filtering predicated. For example, you can use built-in function `USER_NAME()` (check the official documentation for the full working example):

```
CREATE SCHEMA Security;  
GO  

CREATE FUNCTION Security.fn_securitypredicate(@SalesRep AS sysname)  
    RETURNS TABLE  
WITH SCHEMABINDING  
AS  
    RETURN SELECT 1 AS fn_securitypredicate_result   
WHERE @SalesRep = USER_NAME() OR USER_NAME() = 'Manager';
```

This function returns 1 when a row in the `SalesRep` column is the same as the user executing the query (`@SalesRep = USER_NAME()`) or if the user executing the query is the Manager user (`USER_NAME() = 'Manager'`).

You can use also [sp_set_session_context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-set-session-context-transact-sql) and [SESSION_CONTEXT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/session-context-transact-sql) to build more complex logic. For example, you can calculated the security access in your `.net` code  and `set session context` for the SQL session your are opening. Then, using `SESSION_CONTEXT` you can check the access in your filtering function.